# Where can I interact with other Esperanto speakers about literature?

Tags: culture, literature

I'd like to interact with other Esperanto speakers (preferably in Esperanto) about literature. I already know about the Literatura Babilejo on Telegram and the Duolingo Esperanto Learners Facebook group. Where else can I find other Esperanto book worms?

Comment: I have written 16 articles in Esperanto, 2 of which I would count as addressing your request: 
“Ĝenaj Ĝemeloj: Wodehouse kaj Roosevelt” and “La Lingvo-Bariero kiel Beletra Rimedo”. 
The articles are available at: http://www.public-domain-materials.com/dosierujo-artikoloj-en-esperanto.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Facebook group *[Literatura Babilejo](https://www.facebook.com/groups/442766379191830/?fref=ts)* has 340 members, who publish posts and comments about Esperanto literature every day. Multiple active members of this group are themselves authors of Esperanto literature.

Comment: That sounds exactly like what I've been looking for!

Answer (score 7):

There is Goodreads, where the is an Esperanto group: https://www.goodreads.com/group/show/10231-esperanto
The discussion isn't very active, but there is a common "bookshelf" where one can see what others add to the group as Esperanto reading material. There are also at least three list with "best books" with Esperanto-related content.

There is also a group on Librarything: https://www.librarything.com/groups/esperanto 
Librarything is a site where people catalogue their "libraries".

I just read about the recurring "[Esperanto sumoo](http://www.esperanto-sumoo.strefa.pl/index.html), a reading event that occurs a few times a year. It also seems to have meet-ups from time to time. It seems to be an ideal location to interact with other readers - physically.

Answer (score 2):

There is a Facebook group- "Cxu vi skajpemas" https://www.facebook.com/groups/skajpanoj. If you write about your interests there, there will be someone who wants to chat and shares them.
I do not know about any other way, so I would be curious what other people will say :)